# Problema para enviar os dados formulário ReactJS

Tags: react, react-hooks

Pessoal estou com a seguinte problema. Tenho um formulário com react-hook e estou tentando enviar uma requisição para salvar os dados, porém estou recebendo o erro : "Request failed with status code 409. Pelo que eu estou entendendo alguns campos estão sendo enviados vazios:

{"message":"client validation failed: firstName: Path `firstName` is required., lastName: Path `lastName` is required., tel: Path `tel` is required., cep: Path `cep` is required., address: Path `address` is required., number: Path `number` is required., neighborhood: Path `neighborhood` is required., city: Path `city` is required., uf: Path `uf` is required."}"

**O componente:**

```js
    const initialValue = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  tel: "",
  cep: "",
  address: "",
  number: "",
  complement: "",
  neighborhood: "",
  city: "",
  uf: "",
};

const NewClientForm = () => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(initialValue);

  const {
    firstName,
    lastName,
    tel,
    cep,
    address,
    number,
    complement,
    neighborhood,
    city,
    uf,
  } = client;

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, setFocus } = useForm();

  const checkCEP = (e) => {
    const cep = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    fetch(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setValue("address", data.logradouro);
        setValue("neighborhood", data.bairro);
        setValue("complement", data.complemento);
        setValue("city", data.localidade);
        setValue("uf", data.uf);
        setFocus("number");
      });
  };

  // const onValueChange = (e) => {
  //   setClient({ ...client, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  //   checkCEP();
  // };

  const addClientDetails = async () => {
    await addClient(client);
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    // handleSubmit(client);
    console.log(e);

    addClientDetails();
    navigate("/client-list");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className={styles.form__group} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">
          Nome
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            {...register("firstName")}
            // value={client.firstName}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="lastName">
          Sobrenome
          <input
            type="text"
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            {...register("lastName")}
            // value={client.lastName}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="tel">
          Telefone
          <input
            type="text"
            id="tel"
            name="tel"
            {...register("tel")}
            // value={client.tel}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="cep">
          CEP
          <input
            id="cep"
            name="cep"
            type="text"
            {...register("cep")}
            onBlur={checkCEP}
            // value={client.cep}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="address">
          Logradouro
          <input
            id="address"
            name="address"
            type="text"
            {...register("address")}
            // value={client.address}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="number">
          Número
          <input
            type="text"
            id="number"
            name="number"
            {...register("number")}
            // value={client.number}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="neighborhood">
          Bairro
          <input
            id="neighborhood"
            name="neighborhood"
            type="text"
            {...register("neighborhood")}
            // value={client.neighborhood}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="complement">
          Complemento
          <input
            type="text"
            id="complement"
            name="complement"
            {...register("complement")}
            // value={client.complement}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="city">
          Localidade
          <input
            id="city"
            name="city"
            type="text"
            {...register("city")}
            // value={client.city}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <label htmlFor="uf">
          UF
          <input
            id="uf"
            name="uf"
            type="text"
            {...register("uf")}
            // value={client.uf}
            // onChange={(e) => onValueChange(e)}
          />
        </label>

        <button
          type="submit"
          className={styles.btn}
          onClick={() => addClientDetails()}
        >
          Salvar Cliente
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**O serviço para adicionar o cliente:**

```js
  export const addClient = async (client) => {
  return await axios.post(`${clientsUrl}/clients/`, client);
};
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda !

Comment: Isso aí é o backend que validou e não encontrou algo. você deve assegurar que os dados necessários para a validação no backend sejam enviados como se espera

Comment: Obrigado Aloiso, vou verificar.